# "Lambda function for the route not found" error running Golang function locally with SAM?

Tags: python, go, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm attempting to write a Lambda function in Golang (doing development on my MacBook with Docker Desktop running) following [this](https://maori.geek.nz/hello-sam-aws-golang-quickstart-dc8b4b8c49ed) quick-start. I perform the following steps:

1. Ran "sam init --runtime go1.x --name testing" to generate a function from the template.
2. Ran "make deps" to go get dependencies.
3. Ran "make build" to build the code that was generated to hello-world/hello-word.
4. Ran "sam local start-api".

Everything looks like it starts correctly:

```
Mounting HelloWorldFunction at http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello [GET]
You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2019-11-16 10:39:19  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But when I curl the endpoint, I get a 502 and I see an error:

```
2019-11-16 10:39:23 Exception on /hello [HEAD]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.31.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2317, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.31.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1840, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.31.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1743, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.31.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.31.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1838, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.31.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1824, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.31.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/local/apigw/local_apigw_service.py", line 172, in _request_handler
    route = self._get_current_route(request)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.31.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samcli/local/apigw/local_apigw_service.py", line 236, in _get_current_route
    raise KeyError("Lambda function for the route not found")
KeyError: 'Lambda function for the route not found'
2019-11-16 10:39:23 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Nov/2019 10:39:23] "HEAD /hello HTTP/1.1" 502 -
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of the lambda docker container are you using? I just tested it with docker image b8e51a982e64 and it worked. Does the go test pass?

Comment: I'm using that same image ID. Running 'go test' results in a pass. Running 'sam deploy' and uploading to Lambda results in the function working as expected as well - I just can't get it working locally.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party on this one and you've probably resolved it already. Without seeing any code, it looks like you've made a HEAD request, rather than a GET request and I suspect you have no route for the HEAD method, only GET.